# Как юзеру добавить пост через форму WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет. Пишу для сайта блок "Отзывы". Сам блок с отзывами уже написал, сделал так: зарегистрировал пост тайп, вывел его на страницу с помощью цикла. Для поста взял тайтл, контент, 2 метабокса (рейтинг и имя).

Теперь нужно реализовать создания поста через форму. Вопрос в том, как это сделать? Какая функция добавляет посты?

П.С. нагуглил wp_insert_post(), но что-то мне не совсем понятен механизм, как принимать данные с формы и отправлять на конкретный пост тайп.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно аяксом. Который при отправке вашей формы, будет передавать данные на бекенд, где вы уже можете их обработать и добавить запись таким образом:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post( [
  'post_type'    => 'your_post_type',
  'post_status'  => 'publish',
  'post_title'   => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['review_title'] ),
  'post_content' => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['review_content'] ),
] );

if( is_wp_error( $post_id ) ){
   wp_send_json_error( [ 'message' => $post_id->get_error_message() ], 401 );
}
```

На счет использования `wp_strip_all_tags();`, тут уже сами смотрите, каким образом вам нужно очищать входящие данные, в зависимости от формы отзывов.